# debgsig-verify fails with gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found while gpg decrypt can verify the detached signature

Tags: gnupg, sign, apt, deb

Why does debsig-verify fail to verify when the `_gpgorigin` detached signature matches the combined `debian-binary control.tar.gz data.tar.gz` file?

Is it because of this `WARNING: This key is not certified with a trusted signature!`?

On `debian:7` docker container package signing worked well and on `debian:9.8` it fails with

```
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
    gpg: processing message failed: Unknown system error
    debsig: subprocess getKeyID returned error exit status 2
```

## Signing Process

```
# Unpack
ar x unsigned.deb

# Generate combine file
cat debian-binary control.tar.gz data.tar.gz > combined

# Create detached signature for combined
gpg -abs -o _gpgorigin combined

# Repack
ar rc signed.deb _gpgorigin debian-binary control.tar.gz data.tar.gz
```

## Verify detached signature (seems successful)

```
gpg --output doc --decrypt _gpgorigin
        Detached signature.
        Please enter name of data file: combined
        gpg: Signature made Thu Apr 25 22:43:37 2019 UTC
        gpg:                using RSA key AAAABBBBCCCCDDDD996FCC98FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
        gpg: Good signature from "mygroup Testing <testing@mygroup.net>" [unknown]
        gpg: WARNING: This key is not certified with a trusted signature!
        gpg:          There is no indication that the signature belongs to the owner.
        Primary key fingerprint: AAAA BBBB CCCC DDDD 996F CC98 FFFF FFFF FFFF FFFF
```

## Verify signed package (fails)

```
debsig-verify -v -d signed.deb

    debsig: Starting verification for: signed.deb
    debsig:         getSigKeyID: got FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF for origin key
    debsig: Using policy directory: /etc/debsig/policies/FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
    debsig:   Parsing policy file: /etc/debsig/policies/FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF/mygroup-test.pol
    debsig:     parsePolicyFile: parsing '/etc/debsig/policies/FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF/mygroup-test.pol'
    debsig:     parsePolicyFile: completed
    debsig:     Checking Selection group(s).
    debsig:       Processing 'origin' key...
    gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
    gpg: processing message failed: Unknown system error
    debsig: subprocess getKeyID returned error exit status 2
```

## Key Listing for policie's keyring

```
 gpg --no-default-keyring --keyring  /usr/share/debsig/keyrings/FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF/pubring.gpg --list-sigs
/usr/share/debsig/keyrings/FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF/pubring.gpg
-------------------------------------------------------
pub   rsa2048 2017-06-19 [SC]
      AAAABBBBCCCCDDDD996FCC98FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
uid           [ unknown] MyGroup Testing <testing@mygroup.net>
sig 3        FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF 2017-06-19  MyGroup Testing <testing@mygroup.net>
sub   rsa2048 2017-06-19 [E]
sig          FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF 2017-06-19  MyGroup Testing <testing@mygroup.net>
```

Answer (score 2):

I've just had a similar problem, and found a number of things that I was doing wrong, that aren't obvious from the documentation/examples:

1. make sure that the policy file has the XML namespace using https (not http as the few examples use) i.e. `<Policy xmlns="https://www.debian.org/debsig/1.0/">`
2. the 'keyring' file isn't a keyring, it's just a (public) key.
3. the 'keyring' file must NOT be ASCII-armoured.

With the above changes, package verification succeeded (Ubuntu 18.04)

Comment: oooooh.  Thank you so much. I am using http which was A - OK in earlier debian

Comment: I believe I have a similar problem, but after changing ``http`` to ``https`` I still cannot make ``debsig-verify`` work.  I created a new question in superuser, https://superuser.com/questions/1504081/ .

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error.
To clarify Anthony's answer, the key file cannot be imported to the keyring. 
It has to be a public key that is copied to the keyring folder.
(Example using DDDF2F4CE732A79A)

**This will cause the  error**

```
$ gpg --no-default-keyring \
      --keyring /usr/share/debsig/keyrings/DDDF2F4CE732A79A/debsig.gpg \
      --import <public key>
```

**This will work**

```
$ cp <public key> /usr/share/debsig/keyrings/DDDF2F4CE732A79A/debsig.gpg
```